# Having issues setting up a FreeRADIUS server for network authentication with a TP-Link router

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, radius

I saw my router (TP-Link [TL-WR940N](https://www.tp-link.com/en/home-networking/wifi-router/tl-wr940n/) Hardware Version 6) had multiple authentication methods. I switched it to WPA2-Enterprise. I Googled a Radius Server and I found this video [*How to install and configure free radius server in Windows PC*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tfC5TNUk0pc). I did similar things to this video, but it keeps saying something along the lines of:

> “No user-password attribute or chap-password attribute.”

I got the project off [FreeRADIUS’s website (freeradius.net) on the web archive](https://web.archive.org/web/*/freeradius.net).

Comment: So you say you got the project for `freeradius.net` off of the web archive, but why not go to the official site that exists today on [freeradius.org](https://freeradius.org)?

Comment: the original website wont load so I had to use the archive to download the original file
also freeradius.org is for linux not windows the .net is for windows